# how to get the gps data from a jetson nano?

Tags: python, gps, nvidia-jetson-nano

suppose i have a jetson nano whit an 4g Module for Jetson Nano, like this

https://www.waveshare.com/sim7600g-h-4g-for-jetson-nano.htm

now how i can use python to generate the gps data? is there any library or something that can do this job? or do i need to set up something like a flask/django web to read the gps data from an get/post method or so?

any help you can give me would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a library called gpsd. Use python as an interface and with thr help of gpsd you'll be able to fetch all NMEA data. Go through the documentation. I used it about 3-4 years ago and it was helpful.

Comment: I suppose you'll be able to get someone's code on GitHub if you find for it at the right places :P.  If you found this useful, pls upvote it and accept it as the answer.

Comment: this was really useful! i would like to ask you if you know how to get the ip of the nano conected via 4g? or how can i connect the nano if the ip is not the best way?

Comment: Hey. Easiest technique is to use a monitor and connect the 4g module too. Then using the arp broadcast a message and see all IPs connected (google this. You'll find plethora of resources). Out of those 1 or 2 IPs your 4g module will be one. Then you can set a static IP for the same so that it doesn't change on reboot.